# AS3 ScrollPane mouse wheel event not working outside IE

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer, browser, scrollpane

I have several ScrollPane instances in my project and when testing locally - just by running the swf - scrolling the mouse wheel while over them scrolls the content. However, when I run it in Google Chrome or FireFox the mouse wheel doesn't do anything, even if I click on the content first. Testing in IE though I can scroll the content with the mouse wheel. I can't seem to find another problem like this online but I was hoping someone might have an idea what could be wrong?

Thanks, Heather

Comment: Check player version for FireFox and Chrome ( http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html )

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that wasn't the problem unfortunatley

Comment: I need to see the sources...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this problem wasn't specific to ScrollPane but was to do with mousewheel events being intercepted by the browser and not reaching the swf.

I managed to solve this in the index.html file when embedding the swf by setting wmode = "window" (previously it had been "opaque") - the wmode property "Sets the Window Mode property of the SWF file for transparency, layering, positioning, and rendering in the browser" http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html